# How to find out whether NSScrollView is currently scrolling

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

How can I find out whether my NSScrollView is currently scrolling?
On iOS I can use the delegate but despite of googling a lot I can't find a way to do this on the Mac.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can receive notification NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification like shown below

```
NSView *contentView = [scrollview contentView];

[contentView setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES];

// a register for those notifications on the content view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(boundDidChange:)
                                             name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                                           object:contentView];
```

The notification method

```
- (void)boundDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // get the changed content view from the notification
    NSClipView *changedContentView=[notification object];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As of OS X 10.9 there is also [`NSScrollView.willStartLiveScrollNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification). It's posted on the main thread at the beginning of a user scroll event.

E.g.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scrollViewDidScroll), name: NSScrollView.willStartLiveScrollNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: Why is the selector `scrollViewDidScroll` in the past tense, but the notification name `willStartLiveScrollNotification` in the future tense?

Answer (score 2):

my two cents for OSX mojave / swift 5

```
 let nc =  NotificationCenter.default

    nc.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(scrollViewWillStartLiveScroll(notification:)),
        name: NSScrollView.willStartLiveScrollNotification,
        object: scrollView
    )

    nc.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(scrollViewDidEndLiveScroll(notification:)),
        name: NSScrollView.didEndLiveScrollNotification,
        object: scrollView
    )
```

....

```
   @objc func scrollViewWillStartLiveScroll(notification: Notification){
        #if DEBUG
        print("\(#function) ")
        #endif
    }


    @objc func scrollViewDidEndLiveScroll(notification: Notification){
        #if DEBUG
        print("\(#function) ")
        #endif
    }
```